# PHP Error: Call to a member function storeFormValues() on a non-object

Tags: php

I have an error and I don't know what I am doing wrong. Help, please, with this :)
So, I have a class named Activities and in it a I have few functions as here:

```
class Activities
{
  public $content = null;

  public function __construct( $data=array() ) {
    if ( isset( $data['content'] ) ) $this->content = $data['content'];
  }

  public function storeFormValues ( $params ) {

    $this->__construct( $params );

  }

  public static function getData() {
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM exceptions WHERE name = 'atrakcje'";
    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->execute();
    $row = $st->fetch();
    $conn = null;
    if ( $row ) return new Activities( $row );
  }

  public function update() {

    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "UPDATE exceptions SET content=:content WHERE name = 'atrakcje'";
    $st = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":content", $this->content, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->execute();
    $conn = null;
  }
}
```

And I have a function editActivities() in my little Admin Panel I made:

```
function editActivities() {

  $results = array();
  $results['pageTitle'] = "Edytuj Atrakcje";
  $results['formAction'] = "editActivities";

  if ( isset( $_POST['saveChanges'] ) ) {

    $activities->storeFormValues( $_POST );
    $activities->update();
    header( "Location: admin.php?action=editActivities&status=changesSaved" );

  } elseif ( isset( $_POST['cancel'] ) ) {

    header( "Location: admin.php?action=editActivities" );

  } else {

    $results['activities'] = Activities::getData();
    require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/admin/editActivities.php" );

  }
}
```

Also I have a HTML Form to make changes. But when I submit filled form I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function storeFormValues() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin.php on line 285
```

285 line in my code is here:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['saveChanges'] ) ) {

    $activities->storeFormValues( $_POST );
    $activities->update();
```

I don't know what's going on. I have just the same code to edit other Articles and Users and I can't figure out what's bad here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where is the code that shows you instantiating $activities before trying to call storeFormValues()?

Comment: whatever $activities is in line 285, it seems not to be an instance of your Activities class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$activities` is not instantiated, so you can't call one of its instance methods. You ought to instantiate it with

```
$activities = new Activities($_POST);
```

Also, in your static function `getData` you either return an `Activities` or NULL, depending on the value of `$row`. But this may make `$results['activities']` sometimes an object and sometimes not, which is tricky to handle and might result in the same error being raised again.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
$activities = new Activities();
$activities->storeFormValues( $_POST );
....
```